# Fatal error in downloader

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-connect, downloader

I'm experiencing a fatal error in the downloader of my Magento installation. When I login to the downloader I receive this error:

```
Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'DEFAULT_SCONFIG_FILENAME' in /downloader/Maged/Connect.php on line 167
```

I checked what's on this line, and this is what it says:

```
if(!$this->_sconfig || $reload) {
        $this->_sconfig = new Mage_Connect_Singleconfig(
            $this->getConfig()->magento_root . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
            . $this->getConfig()->downloader_path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
            . Mage_Connect_Singleconfig::DEFAULT_SCONFIG_FILENAME
        );
    }
```

I'm not seeing another reference to `DEFAULT_SCONFIG_FILENAME`. How do I fix this?

Comment: give write permission to downloder folder and try again

Comment: Already did this. I gave the downloader folder the permissions 777. It gives me the same error.

Comment: Does someone have another idea?